# Indexing N dimensional matrix

Tags: python, numpy

How to query across across axis 1 using axis 0?

For example, for the following 3D matrix:

```
data = np.array([
[[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5]],
[[3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,7]],
[[5,6,7,8], [6,7,8,9]]
])
```

Shape of (3, 2, 4)

And query indexes:

In case of: idxs = [0, 0, 1]

Result:

```
[
[1,2,3,4],
[3,4,5,6],
[6,7,8,9]
]
```

In case of: idxs = [1, 0, 0]

Result:

```
[
[2,3,4,5],
[3,4,5,6],
[5,6,7,8]
]
```

How can it be done?

Comment: For the specific case you put, the answer is : data[:, 0, :]. I'm not sure what result you expect in the case of [1,0,0] for example, could you clarify ?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at [numpy slicing](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.indexing.html) it's pretty straightforward

Comment: You need advanced indexing `data[np.arange(data.shape[0]),idxs]`